# Error making a docker image in a raspberry pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make my own image of the random scheduler in a Raspberry Pi Kubernetes cluster, but when I use the command

```
docker build -t angel96eur/marton-randomscheduler .
```

I get this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  185.9kB
Step 1/13 : FROM golang:1.11-alpine as backend
 ---> 2bf7a3ec2cd3
Step 2/13 : RUN apk add --update --no-cache bash ca-certificates curl git make tzdata
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e5d9d12a87e
Step 3/13 : RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/martonsereg/scheduler
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 98179cd910c6
Step 4/13 : ADD Gopkg.* Makefile /go/src/github.com/martonsereg/scheduler/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70c615ff07f6
Step 5/13 : WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/martonsereg/scheduler
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7cdb09255a20
Step 6/13 : RUN make vendor
 ---> Running in 2f0555b065c7
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | INSTALL_DIRECTORY=bin DEP_RELEASE_TAG=v0.5.0 sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5230  100  5230    0     0  14487      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14487
ARCH = arm
OS = linux
Will install into bin
Release Tag = v0.5.0
Fetching https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/tag/v0.5.0..
Fetching https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.5.0/dep-linux-arm..
Request failed with code 404
make: *** [Makefile:37: bin/dep-0.5.0] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c make vendor' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Where the error could be?

Comment: The golang/dep repo `v0.5.0` doesn't have a `dep-linux-arm` release asset. The closest one that has an arm version seems to be`v0.5.2` so you might want to change your `DEP_RELEASE_TAG` to that. You can double check here: https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/

Comment: Could you also post your full Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs show the release download failed while building your container:

```
Release Tag = v0.5.0
Fetching https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/tag/v0.5.0..
Fetching https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.5.0/dep-linux-arm..
Request failed with code 404
```

Looking at the [release assets](https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/), golang/dep repo `v0.5.0` doesn't have a `dep-linux-arm` release asset. The closest one that has an arm version seems to be`v0.5.1` so you might want to change your `DEP_RELEASE_TAG` to that.

Comment: this is the Dockerfile

```

Comment: @Ángel Can you edit your post to include the dockerfile instead of posting as comment? Thanks!